# error in creating custom layout while listview using base adapter in android

Tags: android, android-layout, baseadapter

I am fetching the images and names from mysql database through the url using json. i can view the images in list view.but not names . i want create custom view inside the getview method.but create cusotom view it show error in logcat..please see the my code and edit my code send to me

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static final Context Context = null;
String qrimage;
Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
Activity activity = null;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ImageAdapter(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");
            itemname = image.getString("itemname");
            map.put("itemname", image.getString("itemname"));
            System.out.println(itemname);

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                    qrimageBytes.length);
            int width = 100;
            int height = 100;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                    true);

            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // tv[i].setText(itemname);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
 public class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



//  return mImages[position];
      ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
            holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(map.get("itemname"));
        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Layout xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image"
  android:layout_width="50dip"
  android:layout_height="50dip" android:src="@drawable/stub"    
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"  android:textSize="20dip" 
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I want append the mimages in imageview and itemname to textview. finally i want mimages and itemname as listview

Comment: what error it shows in Logcat? shows us the Logcat output.

Comment: it shows null pointer exception.and it shows error line convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);

Comment: i am can display images in listview. return mimages[posstion] in getview method. now i want display mimages and itemname in listview. please edit my code and send to me

Comment: make sure that your inflater instance is not null.

Comment: please edit my code i want display mimages and itemname in listview please send me

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use the statement,

   private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

Just leave it as

```
private static LayoutInflater inflater;
```

1. Don't put the inflator inside the for...loop and the try{}catch block. if it throws an exception, your inflator will not be initialized.
2. Initialize the inflator on the first line of the constructor itself.
3. Alternately use,

   inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

In your constructor,

1. Check the way you are creating the hashmap, its erroneous.
2. Your holder needs a Imageview that you need to update along with your TextView in getView().

Comment: ya. this is working.. how to append mimages and itemname to listview

Comment: please replay how to add vi to my mimages and itemname.. i want listview mimages and text in listview.. please replay

Comment: Go through this tutorial on how to use custom ListViews. Though the tutorial explains the use of srray adapter, it'll help u get the concept. http://www.shubhayu.com/android/listview-with-arrayadapter-and-customized-items

Comment: if the answer works for you, you could select it as your correct answer and up it, so that other users know which post to follow. :)

Comment: Your code needs some work, I suggest you understand the concept first. I am editing my answer, to guide you through it.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
```

Comment: try with your activity object

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to pass String Array instead of JSONArray to the ImageAdapter Class. Get all values before you call setAdapter, store them into String array and pass it. You need to change in ImageAdapter Class accordingly.

Comment: JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("names");
   list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
       adapter=new ImageAdapter(this, json);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);. if i can pass json only i can get images from database other wise i can't get. here no string value is there to pass to the image adapter